# How can get images from wikipedia api?

Tags: django, wikipedia-api

i have the product keyword, i need images from wikipedia for that search keyword to display in my web application. is it possible? i'm doing this application in python/django framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some [simple searching](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aTutorial#How_to_use_it) has this example in the **tutorial**, for fetching search result images:

```
?action=query&titles=San_Francisco&prop=images&imlimit=20&format=jsonfm.
```

You can use `urllib2` to fetch the results, etc.

Comment: This will list the images from the *article* “San Francisco”. And I'm not sure the keywords from the question will always match article names exactly.

Comment: I was just pointing out that the wiki tutorial makes it quite clear how to do those kinds of queries. There are other queries which would return specific pages. The keywords may not match exactly but some obvious error checking is required. It depends on what the OP has tried already. Which is...nothing?